# JavaScript array - 0 length when used but Chrome can see correct length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is driving me absolutely nuts being a beginner JavaScript meddler.

I have an array called arrayA with the following data (in my actual code I declare arrayA with [] and then use $.getJSON to ingest a file that contains data):

```
 arrayA = [
    {
        "Key":  "Key1",
        "Value":  {
                      "info1":  "298431",
                      "info2":  "55.035",
                      "info3":  "11.375",
                  },
        "Name":  "Key1"
    }
]
```

In my HTML page, I have a script tag/section and this is defined there. After arrayA, I have a function called funcA() where I try and do "stuff" This includes things like finding the index for "Key1" as an example.

When doing console.log in line it always reports as 0 but when checking the length using Chrome's console it reports the correct number of objects (8950).

Not really sure what is the problem. Potentially variable scoping or the way the arrayA is initialised and loaded with data? Could someone help?

For completeness:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrayA = [];

$.getJSON('./source.json', function(data) {
    arrayA = data;                  
});

function funcA() {
    //Do stuff to find indexOf "Key1"
}
</script>
```

/D

Comment: where are the logging statements? This will probably help [How to return the response of an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: How do you use / invoke `funcA()` ? Why not showing that part of code?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick responses on all the possibilities. I shall try and reply in turn and update the question with more information as per some of the requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that when `funcA()` runs, the data is not yet available.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrayA = [];

$.getJSON('./source.json', function(data) {
    arrayA = data;                  
    console.log('Data was loaded', arrayA);
});

function funcA() {
    //Do stuff to find indexOf "Key1"
    console.log('funcA() ran');
}
</script>
```

Then you'll see in which order things happen. Of course `$.getJSON` being an async function, you can't rely things always happening in the same order. Therefore you should look into promises or callbacks, and not use global variables.

Comment: Not much of an explanation

Comment: Probably putting `funcA();` inside the ajax callback could be a useful example.

Comment: Your update doesn't even call `funcA()`

Comment: @charlietfl Neither does the original code. I'm simply trying to show where to insert logging statements to make some sense of what's happening when.

Comment: Well it does nothing to help OP understand the issue providing code that won't demonstrate anything

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning data to `arrayA` asynchronously - when you are first inspecting the callback function for `getJSON` has not yet completed. If you would like to operate on the data you could call `funcA` inside the callback:

```
$.getJSON('./source.json', function(data) {
  arrayA = data;
  funcA();                 
});
```